# How do I add margin values to inflated ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

This is my code for how each row looks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/recipe_container"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="#f1f1f1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:text="DUMMY TEXT"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recipe_time_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DUMMY TEXT"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recipe_difficulty_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DUMMY TEXT"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_thumbnail_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sladice"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I have margin set, if I check preview it is also shown.

I populated with inflate this listivew.
This is activity_sladice.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recipe_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.recepti.Sladice"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

</ListView>
```

Now each row is together, there is no spacing between left, right, bottom , top.

If I add margin or padding to listview it only works on the entire list, not on each row.

How to do it? I know I can add divider between each row but I also want spacing right and left.

This is getView method from custom adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View recipeView = convertView;
    ReceptThumbnail recipe = getItem(position);

    // Inflate view if to be inflated
    if (recipeView == null) {
        recipeView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView recipeName = (TextView) recipeView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_name_text_view);
    recipeName.setText(recipe.getName());

    TextView recipeTime = (TextView) recipeView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_time_text_view);
    recipeTime.setText(recipe.getTime());

    TextView recipeDifficulty = (TextView) recipeView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_difficulty_text_view);
    recipeDifficulty.setText(recipe.getDifficulty());

    ImageView recipeImage = (ImageView) recipeView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_thumbnail_image_view);
    recipeImage.setImageResource(recipe.getImageResourceID());
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you're inflating views for your items? The getView method.

Comment: I edited now and added getview method

Comment: Ok, I solved it. I tried this before but it didnt work, so maybe I checked wrong or android studio preview doesnt show correctly. I just added another LinearLayout around first xml with same height, width and now it works.

Comment: Also you could try to switch to RecyclerView - it may be more consistent regarding cell topmost layout params.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add margins to the ListView, add margns to the listview.
If you want to add margins to the items, add margins to the items.

It is simple.

However, I suggest you to use ConstraintLAyout. And RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try using padding in the LinearLayout, and create another LinearLayout as a child of the original, and move the background attribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

try setting margin programmatically in getView method using below method.

```
public static void setMarginLeft(View v, int left) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =   
                                (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(left, params.topMargin, 
                            params.rightMargin, params.bottomMargin);
}
```